# Mvc raw has no output

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have simplified the issue to it's simplest form. Why does this not output anything on my page ?

```
@if(true){Html.Raw("<a>test</a>");}
```

**EDIT**

This does work however:

```
@if ( true ) { <span>@Html.Raw( "<a>test</a>" )</span>}
```

Comment: try using MvcHtmlString.Create() instead... Though, I'm skeptical about this too. Usually I use <text></text> tags around rendered code within @If branch. I can't give you a solid reason why, but this is standard behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because the Razor engine is confused "if it needs to" or "how to deal" with the first type of code you wrote. That will work if you do this:

```
@if(true){@Html.Raw("<a>test</a>");}
```

Notice the `@` at the beginning of the `Html` syntax. There's [an explanation here by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) about that. A summary of it is this:

> Not all content container blocks start with a tag element tag, though,
>   and there are scenarios where the Razor parser can’t implicitly detect
>   a content block.
>
> Razor addresses this by enabling you to explicitly indicate the
>   beginning of a line of content by using the @: character sequence
>   within a code block.  The @: sequence indicates that the line of
>   content that follows should be treated as a content block.

Now I believe that applies to to your specific issue.

Comment: Thank you that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(true){Html.Raw("<a>test</a>");}
```

Above lines will not give you html output because razor Parser infers code ending by reading the opening and the closing characters or HTML elements.
Since, your code does not contain any html elements inside your if condition so parser will eveluate this as a expression just like we do in our controllers.

```
@if ( true ) { <span>@Html.Raw( "<a>test</a>" )</span>}
```

This works because `@Html.Raw` is wrapped under span element.

Comment: Thanks I suspected as much was just wondering why this happens , von v. had a nice explanation above.